# How to get data from database and binding it dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm filling list with country objects and I want to bind it dropdownlist with its id.But I want to show it with CountryName property. When I save the data it should go with CounrtyId property. There is a relation with book and country Country_CountryID is field of Book in database. How can I do that.

Models

```
 public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime Holiday { get; set; }

        public string WeekendDayOne { get; set; }

        public string WeekendDayTwo { get; set; }
    }
 public class Book
    {

        public int BookID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime BookCheckOutDate { get; set; }


        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime BookReturnDate { get; set; }

        public Country Country { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookID,BookCheckOutDate,BookReturnDate")] Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Books.Add(book);
            List<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(book);
    }

 // GET: Books/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();

        ViewBag.CountryName = countries;

        // I want to bind countries with a dropdownlist

        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Book</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookCheckOutDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookCheckOutDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookCheckOutDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookReturnDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookReturnDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookReturnDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    //Should come CountryName DropDownlist

}
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show you view code and the GET method. And why do you have `List<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();` in your POST method when you don't even use it.

Comment: Do you need both 'Country' and 'Book' object on the same page?

Comment: No, I just want to calculate a late penalty of book return. But when enter information about book checkout and bookreturn i have to select country.

Comment: I used it in my post method becuase when user click create it is going to calculate late penalty.

Comment: Cant help unless your show your view code and the GET method

Comment: // GET: Books/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();

            ViewBag.CountryName = countries; 

            return View();
        }

Comment: Edit your question and include the view.

Comment: Its not really clear what those models are. Your `[Key]` attribute suggests they are data models but your use of `[DisplayFormat]` and `[DataType]` (which are view specific attributes) suggests its a view model. And if its a data model, your missing your navigation property for Country - `public int CountryID { get; set; }` and `public virtual Country Country { get; set; }`

Comment: So how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

In order to include the `CountryID` on book creation, you should include it in your `Book` model and use proper attributes to mark it as [ForeignKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Country` property on `Book`.

Then use it

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrynames)
```

This way, you could bind it the same way as all other properties

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookID,BookCheckOutDate,BookReturnDate,CountryID")] Book book)
```

If this does not work out of the box, you may load the specified country object by ID before saving the book.

**Original**

You want to populate a dropdown list, so your target cshtml is something along the line

```
@Html.DropDownList("listname", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrynames)
```

As you can see, ViewBag.countrynames needs to be a list of `SelectListItem`, so in code behind you should assign

```
ViewBag.countrynames = countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.CountryID.ToString(), Text = x.CountryName });
```

This way, the country name is visible in the resulting html page and the country id is the internal representation of the selected value

Comment: Yes i can see countries. But when i click create it's going null. How i can send it's CountryID

Comment: @Timosis In the other Answer you mentioned Country_CountryID. Is this a model property or only an auto-generated database column? If it is a database column, you need to update your model to explicitely contain the property, otherwise just change my `model.CountryID` and the binding annotation in `Create` to the real property.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookID,BookCheckOutDate,BookReturnDate")] Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            List<Country> countries = db.Countries.ToList();
            //Put this 'countries' in ViewBag like 
            ViewBag.Countries = countries;
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(book);
    }
```

Now on view, you can cast this back like

```
 List<Country> countries =(List<Country>)ViewBag.Countries;
```

and then iterate through each item.

```
<select id="select1" >
   <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
   @foreach(var cnt in countries)
   {
   <option value='@cnt.Id'>@cnt.Name</option>
   }
</select>
```

Comment: Book and Countr has a relation does it save Country Id in book Country_CountryID

Comment: Book must have country_Id as well as Country table too must have list of books if you are using entity framework and has lazyloading on (which is default).

Comment: It has Country_CountryID